# How can I solve msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' from binance API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance

I am trying to create a test order using Binance API but I have this error message msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' I tried to get the signature using the secret key and timestamp = Date.now() but didn't work.
My code is:

```
const credentials = require('./credentials');
const crypto = require('crypto');

function testNewOrder(symbol,side,type,timeInForce,quantity,price) {
    const url = credentials.urlTest;
    let timeStamp = Date.now();
    let signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', credentials.secretKeyTest).update(`timestamp=${timeStamp}`).digest('hex')
    console.log(signature,timeStamp,timeStamp2);
    fetch(`${url}/api/v3/order/test?symbol=${symbol}&side=${side}&type=${type}&timeInForce=${timeInForce}&quantity=${quantity}&price=${price}&timestamp=${timeStamp}&signature=${signature}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-MBX-APIKEY": credentials.apiKeyTest
      },

    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then( data=> {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

testNewOrder('BTCUSDT','SELL','LIMIT','GTC','0.02','42000');
```

Comment: do you have access to the documentation that states how this signature should be created? have you seen https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-signature-examples shows exactly what you need to do i.e. sign the whole "message" not just the timestamp part

Comment: also, well documented on binance site https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security - not sure why you're only signing the timestamp

Comment: @Bravo I read the whole documentation and I believe I am doing the exact thing that is showed in the node.js folder [link](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-signature-examples/blob/master/nodejs/signature.js) . `credentials.secretKeyTest` has my apiSecret.

Comment: TL;DR - do what is documented [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security) not some rando github page that explains the concept generally

Comment: It was not a random repository! Is the official one. Indeed is the one you sent me in the first comment.

Comment: Just read the documents instead, or try to understand the nature of the example ... there's probably a good reason that repo has the phrase **Code in this repository should NOT be used in production** - because of the nature of the code - read what it is, then read the documentation that **tells you WHAT you need to sign** - the second link I sent

Comment: or read [Official Documentation for the Binance APIs and Streams](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs)

Comment: The problem was that I was using only timestamp as a param to hash the signature. I did have to use the rest of the params like symbol,side, etc in the .update() function

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, Hope this will help

```
import { createHmac } from "crypto";

const SECRET = "";

export const addSignature = (params) => {
  // Object to query string
  const queryString = Object.keys(params)
    .map((key) => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join("&");

  const signature = createHmac("sha256", SECRET)
    .update(queryString)
    .digest("hex");

  return {
    ...params,
    signature,
  };
};

addSignature({
  symbol: "BTC",
  // ...
});
```